# Comparing a start datetime and end datetime from php with a date in Javascript

Tags: javascript

After reading many question here relating to this subject I am still having issues resolving my problem.

I am having issues with comparing dates-times in JavaScript. I am reading the "startdate" and "enddate" from a data table where there are two records.

I am using the line below to create my "nowdate":

```
    nowdate = ('0' + (d.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2)  + "-" +('0' + d.getDate()).slice(-2)  + "-" + d.getFullYear()  + " " + ('0' + d.getHours()).slice(-2) + ":" + ('0' + d.getMinutes()).slice(-2);
```

This gives me:

```
Now date:   03-01-2019 11:28
Start date: 03-01-2019 23:59
End date :  03-08-2019 23:59

Now date:   03-01-2019 11:28
Start date: 04-01-2019 23:59
End date:   04-30-2019 23:59
```

I then need to know if the "startdate" and "enddate" are between "Now date".

```
if (new Date(startdate) >= new Date(nowdate) && new Date(nowdate) <= new Date(enddate)) {
console.log("Active: ");
} else if (new Date(nowdate) < new Date(enddate)) {
console.log("Scheduled: ");
} else {
console.log("Complete: ");
}
```

EDITED CODE:

```
// RECORD 1
MOMENT NOW DATE:  03-01-2019 14:03
MOMENT START DATE:  03-01-2019 23:03
MOMENT END DATE:  03-08-2019 23:03
// RECORD 2
MOMENT NOW DATE:  03-01-2019 14:03
MOMENT START DATE:  04-01-2019 23:04
MOMENT END DATE:  04-30-2019 23:04


var nowdate;
            var d = new Date();
            nowdate = (d.getFullYear() + "-" + ('0' + (d.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2))  + "-" + ('0' + d.getDate()).slice(-2)  + " " + ('0' + d.getHours()).slice(-2) + ":" + ('0' + d.getMinutes()).slice(-2);
            
            nowdate = moment(nowdate).format('MM-DD-YYYY HH:MM');
            var startdate2 = moment(startdate2).format('MM-DD-YYYY HH:MM');
            var enddate2 = moment(enddate2).format('MM-DD-YYYY HH:MM');
        
            console.log("MOMENT NOW DATE: ", nowdate);
            console.log("MOMENT START DATE: ", startdate2);
            console.log("MOMENT END DATE: ", enddate2);
            
            if (startdate2 >= nowdate ||  enddate2 <= nowdate) {
                console.log("Active: ");
            } 
            
            else if (startdate2 > nowdate) {
                console.log("Scheduled: ");
            }
```

The issue I have is both records are show as "Active". Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: For ```Date``` constructor you need format ```yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm```, your format gives me "Invalid Date". Date objects you can then compare using ```getTime``` or ```valueOf``` methods. If you had a Date object before, like in your "nowdate" code, I'd use it in the first place.

Comment: You should use a _sortable_ date format (like f.e. `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm`) to begin with - then string comparison is enough already, and you don’t need to convert the value into Date instances first.

Comment: Hi, I have change the format of the dates Now date:  2019-03-01 11:59
 Start date :  2019-03-01 23:59,  End date :  2019-03-08 23:59 But I still get both record showing "Active".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have stated, you have to provide a valid date format string, if using `new Date()` this way. You can either parse your string for date parts and construct it:

```
const dt = new Date(2019, 2, 1, 11, 28); // months are 0 index based
```

Or, you can use something like [MomentJs](http://momentjs.com/) or [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/) to parse your dates, and then do your diff check. Moment is going to give you the greatest flexibility to provide your own format to parse against.

For instance, you can use Moment to properly parse a date string in nearly any format, by providing the format to Moment. Say you have your current date string, from your backend, as `03-01-2019 14:03`. Using Moment, you parse this via `const sd = moment('03-01-2019 14:03', 'MM-DD-YYYY HH:mm')`. Get the current date, with Moment, via `const now = moment()`. Then compare `sd > now`.

Comment: Hi Steve, I am now using the following code. It still returns both record as "Active". Can you see where I am going wrong. Please see edited question. Thanks.

Comment: With regards to Moment, you're confusing 'format'ting the output of a date vs parsing a date. See my edited answer for help.